# No headphone sound (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: sound, headphones

Everything works fine. Ubuntu 16.04 detects when headphones are plugged but there is no sound in the headphone anyway.

```
$ aplay- l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My laptop has a digital output (optical) and an analogic output (jack). I did not test the optical output. Any hint ? The headphone sound worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04 but I cannot remember what I did.

Comment: can you please add `LANG=C` in front of the `aplay -l`command? like so: `LANG=C aplay -l`, this should set aplay to use english language.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann done !

Comment: No sound in the headphone BUT the sound still playing in the speakers as if the headphones were not plugged

Comment: most laptops I know/used did this completely on themselves: headphones in and they switched the sound to them, headphones out and the switched back to the speakers.